# Django DB Migration InconsistentMigrationHistory when running migrate

Tags: python, django, django-migrations

I am unable to migrate my django after running python ./manage.py migrate.

This is what showmigrations is displaying

```
customerweb
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_user_industry
 [X] 0003_auto_20220209_1737
 [X] 0004_userconfiguration_night_surcharge_exempt
 [ ] 0005_auto_20220614_1100
 [X] 0006_orderdelivery_is_order_unique
 [ ] 0007_orderdelivery_client_reference_no
```

I have tried --fake as well as trying to move back by one migrate using

```
python ./manage.py migrate <app_name> <000x_migrate_file>
```

all these is not working as the exeception keeps prompting InconsistentMigrationHistory. I have tried deleting the migration folders as well (keeping init only) but does not work as well.

Comment: are you using custom user model?

Comment: Check django_migrations table in db where the migration history is kept. Try and sync your files to records in django_migrations table while making sure that your models.py is correct and in sync with your database.

Comment: @HimanshuPoddar yes, im using custom user model

Comment: @N3mo for the syncing portion, would it be achievable via --run-syncdb?

Comment: @stranger can you try my answer

Comment: if you have deleted migrations folder try makemigrations with app names in order of creation date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So Django admin expects a default auth model which is `AUTH_USER_MODEL`.  Admin app apply migration as django's auth model Now since you changes the dependency hence the error. Please follow the below steps

1. Take a backup of your database
2. Comment out your created app in `INSTALLED_APPS` and `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'account.User'` in your `settings.py` in project folder
3. Run `python manage.py admin zero`
4. Uncomment lines commented in step 2
5. Run `python manage.py migrate`

Comment: Im using Postgresql. Does this still applies?

Comment: try my updated answer

Comment: worked like a charm! omg thank you! will accept yours as the answer. Thank you for your time again!